# Create models for REST application in Spring Boot with Insomnia

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, insomnia

I heard it is possible to create/define models for REST applications (e.g. in Java/Spring Boot) with Insomnia.
However I couldn't find anything helpful so far.
Also in the documentation and the plugin section I found nothing.
Did anyone hear about this?

Comment: What is *Insomnia*? also, please have a look at [how to ask a question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's a desktop client for interacting with HTTP-based APIs, so you can send requests.